# xmlstarlet add string "null" to self-closing tag

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I am trying to create an sqlite3 loader from data returned from ( Service-Now's REST API ) but it uses self closing tags in it's xml return.

If I could convert the fields from empty self closing to an opening and closing pair with a new value of "null" then I could parse the string if the field was part of an array.

[ CURRENT ]

```
# cat test.xml | xmllint --format -

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <result>
    <serial_number>
      <display_value>6W5QY03</display_value>
      <value>6W5QY03</value>
    </serial_number>
    <location>
      <display_value/>
      <value/>
    </location>
  </result>
</response>
```

[ DESIRED ]

```
# cat test.xml | xmllint --format -

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <result>
    <serial_number>
      <display_value>6W5QY03</display_value>
      <value>6W5QY03</value>
    </serial_number>
    <location>
      <display_value>null<display_value/>
      <value>null<value/>
    </location>
  </result>
</response>
```

Have done a lot of searching but substitution with utilities like ( sed ) I don't think is the way to go.

If I can't put something there I can't test for it. If the return could contain many positive returns one failure testing for status would not work.

```
# cat test.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <response>
      <result>
        <serial_number>
          <display_value>6W5QY03</display_value>
          <value>6W5QY03</value>
        </serial_number>
        <location>
          <display_value/>
          <value/>
        </location>
      </result>
    </response>

# xmlstarlet sel -T -t -v "response/result/location/display_value/text()" test.xml

# echo $?
1

# xmlstarlet sel -T -t -v "response/result/serial_number/display_value/text()" test.xml
6W5QY03
# echo $?
0
```

Comment: Yes I am but the question is if ( xmlstarlet ) can edit the empty tags to (<display>null</display) instead of just ( </display> ) either in place or during the search?

Comment: If I can't put in some value then the only way to test is status like the following but if the results could be ( > 1 ) then the failure would be a false positive for the returns that actually had data in the field.

Comment: Please take a look at the way SO rendered your question. It looks like you didn't anticipate the markup it uses. That said, You seem to have tried something which didn't work, but what is that? If you want to turn this into a good question, consider starting with the [tour] and reading [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [use xslt in xmlstarlet](https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04s02.html) i.e. with this xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <!-- Default copy template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- 
    Template that matches a element that has no node(): 
    text() en element() are both nodes
  -->
  <xsl:template match="*[not(node())]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:text>null</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That is perfect. I am a NOOB and just starting to begin understanding XML and appreciate any help from those that have been on this journey longer than I.

Answer (score 1):

The following xmlstarlet command does what you want. The [`ed`](https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04s03.html) option is used to 1) find all elements that don't have any content and 2) add the text "null" to them.

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "//*[not(node())]" -v "null" test.xml
```

Note that this does not capture just self-closing elements; it captures all empty elements. From an XML point of view, `<x/>` and `<x></x>` are equivalent.

Comment: The timing is almost identical for both working solutions. The straight ( ed ) is simpler but the ( xslt ) looks to be more feature rich if I can understand it's rules. Thanks to both answers.